# Bobril - keyframes rule

Tags: css, typescript, bobril

I am trying to make progress loader component in Bobril, but I do not know how to add keyframes rule. Is there any way how to handle keyframes in Bobril.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**: Actually, a year after the question, [the support for keyframes has been added to bobril](https://github.com/Bobris/Bobril/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1130).

```
const animatetop = b.keyframesDef({
  from: { top: "-300px", opacity: 0 },
  to: { top: 0, opacity: 1 },
});

const modalStyle = b.styleDef({
  // you can use it as a simple animation name
  //   animationName: animatetop,
  //   animationDuration: "0.4s",

  // or as an animation factory
  animation: animatetop("0.4s"),
});
```

I'm keeping the original answer for case of any other unsupported css name refference:

---

**Original Answer**: AFAIK there is no direct support for keyframes in bobril, but you can still use `b.injectCss()` to directly inject keyframes definition and then use it as usual in `b.styleDef()` or `b.style()`.

PS: Because of the lack of direct support, you should ensure uniqueness of the keyframes name by your own means.